# Jquery - How to redirect to previous page and add attribute href in url after click on link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a problem with my code. I am trying to redirect to previous page and add attribute href from this link and add to url. My code doesn't work for some reason. If I try to put an alert instead of window.location then the alert doesn't display anything. What is wrong with my code? Thank you very much.

JQuery:

```
$('#languages li a').click(function(){
      window.location = document.referrer+$(this).attr('href');
      return false;
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="languages" data-role="collapsible"> 
        <h4>English</h4>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="?lang=en">English</a></li>
        <li><a href="?lang=cs">Česky</a></li>
        <li><a href="?lang=de">Deutsch</a></li>
        <li><a href="?lang=ae">English US</a></li>
        <li><a href="?lang=es">Español</a></li>
        <li><a href="?lang=fr">Français</a></li>
        <li><a href="?lang=nl">Nederlands</a></li>
        <li><a href="?lang=tr">Türkçe</a></li>
        <li><a href="?lang=cn">中文</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It's weird, but in fiddle this kind of code works perfectly and I don't see any errors in it, if it just does nothing, it could be jQuery not included, or your js file included before it, but then there would be errors in console. BTW fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/V9Mtc/

Comment: No console errors, Doesn't work for me.

Comment: GUYS I am sorry I am blind and I use this code in different file then original and I forgot to copy to my ftp :) Thnk you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Look the solution here :
http://jsfiddle.net/dzBHA/3/

Html Code :

```
<div id="languages" data-role="collapsible"> 
        <h4>English</h4>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="?lang=en" >English</a></li>
        <li><a href="?lang=cs" >Česky</a></li>
        <li><a href="?lang=de" >Deutsch</a></li>
        <li><a href="?lang=ae" >English US</a></li>
        <li><a href="?lang=es" >Español</a></li>
        <li><a href="?lang=fr" >Français</a></li>
        <li><a href="?lang=nl" >Nederlands</a></li>
        <li><a href="?lang=tr" >Türkçe</a></li>
        <li><a href="?lang=cn" >中文</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And JS (You have to add Location Attribute) :

```
$('#languages li a').on('click', function(){
  //window.location = document.referrer
  alert($(this).attr('href'));
  alert(document.referrer);
  var link =   document.referrer + '' + $(this).attr('href');
  alert(link);
  return false;
});
```

Full Code Page :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>Titre</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="http://yoururl/js.html">Test Referer</a>
        <div id="languages" data-role="collapsible"> 
        <h4>English</h4>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li><a href="?lang=en" >English</a></li>
            <li><a href="?lang=cs" >Cesky</a></li>
            <li><a href="?lang=de" >Deutsch</a></li>
            <li><a href="?lang=ae" >English US</a></li>
            <li><a href="?lang=es" >Español</a></li>
            <li><a href="?lang=fr" >Français</a></li>
            <li><a href="?lang=nl" >Nederlands</a></li>
            <li><a href="?lang=tr" >Türkçe</a></li>
            <li><a href="?lang=cn" >??</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
<script>
$('#languages li a').on('click', function(){
  //window.location = document.referrer
  alert($(this).attr('href'));
  alert(document.referrer);
  var link =   document.referrer + '' + $(this).attr('href');
  alert(link);
  return false;
});
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Edit the url and click on "Test Referer". See the result...

Comment: Doesn't work for me no alert is displayed. I use JQuery 1.8.3

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort it doesn't work because I am blind check my comment below my post to see what happened.

Comment: Ok. I just seen your comment.